# NSDateComponents on IOS6 not working?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, exc-bad-access, nsdatecomponents

I have a simple program which was working with IOS4 and 5.
Now with IOS 6 I'm getting the following error message:

```
2012-10-05 11:08:16.386 app[1698:19d03] 2012-10-05 09:08:11 +0000
2012-10-05 11:08:18.072 app[1698:19d03] 2012-10-05 09:08:11 +0000
2012-10-05 11:08:19.273 app[1698:19d03] 2012-10-05 09:08:11 +0000
2012-10-05 11:08:19.274 app[1698:19d03] 2012-10-05 09:08:11 +0000
2012-10-05 11:08:19.275 app[1698:19d03] 0
2012-10-05 11:08:25.055 app[1698:19d03] 2011-10-05 09:08:11 +0000
2012-10-05 11:08:25.823 app[1698:19d03] (
"<UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0xa167f60; state = Possible; view = <UITableViewCellContentView 0xa168000>; target= <(action=_longPressGestureRecognized:, target=<UIPickerTableViewWrapperCell 0xa168090>)>>")
2012-10-05 11:08:25.824 app[1698:19d03] 2012-10-05 09:08:11 +0000
2012-10-05 11:08:25.824 app[1698:19d03] -[__NSArrayI timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94ef5d0
2012-10-05 11:08:25.825 app[1698:19d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94ef5d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d16012 0x11fae7e 0x1da14bd 0x1d05bbc 0x1d0594e 0x1d25cd3 0xa092 0x120e705 0x145920 0x1458b8 0x206671 0x206bcf 0x205d38 0x17533f 0x175552 0x1533aa 0x144cf8 0x1f4fdf9 0x1f4fad0 0x1c8bbf5 0x1c8b962 0x1cbcbb6 0x1cbbf44 0x1cbbe1b 0x1f4e7e3 0x1f4e668 0x14265c 0x296d 0x28a5)
```

The first run is with two dates which are equal.
On the second run, I've changed the fhDate on the picker as you can see...

The code is simplified a bit for easier reading:

```
aiDate = [adoIgazPicker date];
NSLog(@"%@", aiDate);
fhDate = [forgHelyPicker date];
NSLog(@"%@", fhDate);
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *startDate = fhDate;
NSDate *endDate = aiDate;
NSLog(@"%@", startDate);
NSLog(@"%@", endDate);
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0]; //THIS LINE FAILS IF THE DATES ARE NOT THE SAME
int months = [comps month];
NSLog(@"%i", months);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead of giving links to pictures of console messages and code, put the text in the question itself.

Comment: @user806544 Welcome to stack overflow.  We prefer questions to be self-contained when possible.  Please edit your question to include your code and output directly instead of as pastebin links.

Comment: Hello, sorry, first question here. Edited the question, hopefully this will be ok.

Comment: Why are you creating extra pointer to a date (not talking about the redefinition of `selected` variable).

Comment: Because I just copy pasted the example, and I was lazy to change startDate and endDate variables :\.

Comment: Because I know this code should work, I've created a new empty project, where I pasted this code in the .m, added a button and 2 datepicker to xib, i started the application, and its working :(. So now I revisit my current code, and try to find something which explains why I'm getting the error above.

Comment: But its not starting when I try to run it on iPhone 4.3 simulator :( Xcode version is 4.5. Its funny, I create a single view project with Xcode, in the Project summary, I set Deployment Target to 4.3, then iPhone 4.3 Simulator is available for running, hit command-r and throws a whole bunch of exceptions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
```

with

```
NSInteger months = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit
                                                    fromDate: startDate
                                                      toDate: endDate
                                                     options: 0] month];
```

and now it's working :).