# Unrecognized Selector Error using components:fromDate:toDate:options

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

```
 +(int)weeksBetween:(NSDate *)startDate and:(NSDate *)endDate {

     NSInteger days = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0] day];

     return (days)/7;
 }
```

I have tried multiple ways [components:fromDate:toDate:options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:toDate:options:) and [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743198/nsdatecomponents-on-ios6-not-working) plus others to calculate the difference to see if I can close on the error but I always get the same result below:

```
2013-09-16 08:24:52.268 app[9853:907] -[Day timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f589720

2013-09-16 08:24:52.270 app[9853:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Day timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f589720'
```

I would like weeks as my method says but I have been experimenting with days or months as the code I have seen is generally in that format (I have used the selector for weeks with the same result).

Comment: Are `startDate` and `endDate` actually `NSDate` instances?

Comment: Cause they sure *look* like they're instances of some class called `Day` from those errors.

Comment: The error message says that the class Day does not implement a method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate. Please check this.

Comment: I thought I was passing two NSDates but it turned out that one of them wasn't -> I was passing a Day object incorrectly when it should have been its date property. I appreciate the help - sorry my issue was so trivial.